# Indicator function notation

Tags: functions, notation

Which of the following is correct: $$t \mapsto t\textbf{1}_B(t)$$ 
or $$ t \mapsto t\textbf{1}_B$$
for some set $B$? Here $\textbf{1}$ denotes the indicator function, and the function I am trying to define equals $t$ when $t\in B$.

Comment: $t\mapsto t1_B(t)$ is the correct notation.

Answer (score 3):

The former. The latter makes as much sense as, for example, $x \mapsto x\sin$, which I hope you wouldn't write in a similar context!

Answer (score 0):

As the indicator function takes $t$ as an argument, $t\mathbf 1_B(t)$ is the better notation.